# R Markdown HTML output is shifting bottom text left

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I am working on an HTML output rmd file.  The bottom text is shifting left and I cannot figure out why.[output where bottom text is shifted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3WYh.png)

This is a chunk of the bottom portion of code

```
`<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#msrpt" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="msrpt">
    Base MSRP vs # of EVs (Tesla filtered)
  </a>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="msrpt">
{r, echo = FALSE}
ev_pop_data_prices_g %>%
  filter(make != "TESLA") %>% 
  filter(n>500)%>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = base_msrp))+ 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(y = n, fill = make))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=0.5))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c25)+
  labs(x = "Base MSRP", y = "Number of EVs")
   </div>
</div> 

This is where text is forced left.  `
```

Furthermore, if I try to add a title the text does not show up in the output at all.
[No text when adding title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOqlj.png)

This is a chunk of the bottom portion of code

```
`<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#msrpt" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="msrpt">
    Base MSRP vs # of EVs (Tesla filtered)
  </a>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="msrpt">
{r, echo = FALSE}
ev_pop_data_prices_g %>%
  filter(make != "TESLA") %>% 
  filter(n>500)%>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = base_msrp))+ 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(y = n, fill = make))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=0.5))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c25)+
  labs(x = "Base MSRP", y = "Number of EVs")

   </div>
</div> 

### Different formatting
This is where text is forced left. `
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Insert

```
<div class="card card-body">
```

between

```
<div class="collapse" id="msrpt">
{r, echo = FALSE}


<div class="collapse" id="msrpt">
<div class="card card-body">
{r, echo = FALSE}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).